# Editing all entries in the iPhone phonebook

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an idea and I want to know if it would be possible to implement on iPhone or not. Basically I want to access every entry on the iPhone phonebook, add a prefix before all numbers and then save it again, all without the asking the user to press save on every entry.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Read [Address Book Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html).